# sorting a key-value pair according to values as well as keys

Tags: c++, overriding, stdmap

The PS is on the following lines: 
The report sheet contains `subject --------- marks`. 
Sort the report according to marks in descending order,
If 2 subjects have the same marks, sort those 2 lines as per subjects i.e. the subjects with name which appears first in lexicographical order, is on top.
What would be a good approach to solve this PS?
[This](https://thispointer.com/how-to-sort-a-map-by-value-in-c/) ain't helping much

I initially tried to override std::map. However, it was pointed out by the people trying to help, that it is not a good idea. This was my approach, which also got me confused as to where do I actually assign the values :

```
class map : public std::map<std::string, long, std::greater<>> {
public:
    bool insert(std::pair<std::string, long> pair) {
        //where do I actually "put" the values??
    }
};
```

I tried using

```
typedef std::function<bool(std::pair<std::string, long>, std::pair<std::string, long>)> compareFunc;
compareFunc compare = [](std::pair<std::string, long> lmark, std::pair<std::string, long> rmarks) {
    if (lmarks.second > rmarks.second)
        return true;
    else if ((lmarks.second == rmarks.second) && (lmarks.first < rmarks.first))
        return true;
    return false;
};
std::set<std::pair<std::string, long>, compareFunc> marks;
```

But it fails at run-time

Please suggest me a better one

Comment: the answer does not satisfy you because it says that it is not possible?!? Why do you inherit from `std::map` in the first place? Standard containers are not made to be inherited from

Comment: You override virtual functions and redefine non-virtual ones. `std::map::insert` is not virtual.

Comment: Can you please explain how you intend to use your container? If the container is sorted by values (however one would achieve that), then lookup of elements by key cannot be efficient anymore, so it would become questionable why you don't just use a `std::vector` of key/value pairs or invert the key/value pair.

Comment: btw most maps are implemented using a red-black-tree, but that is an implementation detail. You cannot access that tree without writing non-portable code

Comment: `map` and `multimap` only lets you sort on the maps key (your value). You need another container.

Comment: looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Y: (publicly) Inheriting from standard containers can be done but should not. What you exactly expect to gain from it isnt completely clear, but we could provide you a solution if you made that more clear

Comment: Why not use a `std::set<std::pair<value,key>>`?

Comment: @cpplover Then go with what @TedLyngmo suggested if you need to sort only once or with `std::set<std::pair<mark, subject>, CustomSort>` with a custom sort functor `CustomSort` that sorts correctly.

Comment: @cpplover Also, yes, the question would be much better if a more detailed version of your comment was part of it (you can [edit] it) and you were asking how to implement this sorting (including your approaches up to now) instead of focusing on one approach that is entirely misguided.

Comment: Need to see your code. :)

Comment: what is "PS" ??

Comment: I thought that was the global programmer acronym for `Problem Statement` XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question on [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/bubble-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/pizza-confusion/) This is how I solved it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, long>> hotels;
    long n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    while (n--) {
        std::pair<std::string, long> hotel;
        std::cin >> hotel.first >> hotel.second;
        hotels.push_back(hotel);
    }
    std::sort(hotels.begin(), hotels.end(), [](std::pair<std::string, long> lhotel, std::pair<std::string, long> rhotel)->bool {
        if (lhotel.second > rhotel.second)
            return true;
        else if ((lhotel.second == rhotel.second) && (lhotel.first < rhotel.first))
            return true;
        return false;
    });
    std::cout << hotels.front().first;
    return 0;
}
```

In your solution, just use vector instead of set and all will be fine :)

Just for future references, if you want to deviate from the standard implementation of 
any STL container in c++, always go for vectors instead. Never fails  ;)

Comment: You get that I used your comparator function itself right? :P